Which clauses are emphasized in sentences containing although (or though) or but?
Suppose A and B are clauses.
Which of A and B is more emphasized than the other in

A, although (or though) B.


Although (or though) B, A.

and

A, but B.

Are the answers B, A, and B?

This is a fairly pointless question. The only difference (apart from "popularity") that I know of between though and although is that idiomatically, we never "intensify" the latter, even although I don't think this could be called "ungrammatical". And as to whether you "front" the word though, it makes all the difference in the world what the two things being contrasted actually are. Obviously Though A, B is gonna be klunky if A is some very long complex 50-word assertion. But it's fine if A is fairly short, as in Even though it's late, I don't want to go to bed.

Chatgpt says English sentences often follow a "Given-New" structure. The "Given" part refers to information the listener is likely already aware of, while the "New" part is the new information being conveyed. So there's at least a weak tendency for the second-mentioned assertion to carry more weight. But there are so many other factors (not just phrasing, but intonation) that we can't say much without specific examples. Which will only generate discussion about personal preferences anyway.
